# polymorphic association alternative

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to design a part of my database which should cover users login. My users can login with "local", "facebook" or "google" account.

What I have is a table users that contains two columns, login_type login_id.
The values of login_type can be "local", "facebook" or "google" which refers to three tables: local, facebook and google.
login_id is the id of the login_type referenced table.

I don't like this polymorphic association and would redesign this part to keep the database simple and coherent by creating tables that references as usual with foreign key.

Appreciate any suggestion

Regards

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail what is the structure of the "local", "facebook" and "google" tables, what is their purpose, and how they are related to the rest.  The "which names are" part is not correct English and therefore not understandable.

Comment: basically an users record points to the local, facebook or google table, and the association is done from the value of the column login_type.

Comment: Reverse the FK, let local, facebook and google tables refer to the users table.

Comment: Serg, this is a good trick. Have to add some more logic to the app but absolutely viable. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is a trick known in Object Relational Mapping (ORM) systems as a *discriminator column*.  The problem with it, as you already understand, is that referential integrity goes out the window, because you cannot declare your `login_id` as being a foreign key that maps to another table, because it may map to one of three possible tables, and the table that it maps to is chosen by the value of the `login_type` column.

The way to do this *correctly* might seem a bit strange, but it does guarantee referential integrity.

```
Table users columns:
     id                    primary key
     local_users_id        foreign key, references local_users(id)
     facebook_users_id     foreign key, references facebook_users(id)
     google_users_id       foreign key, references google_users(id)
```

So, the `login_type` column is abandoned, and instead you introduce three nullable foreign keys: `local_users_id`, `facebook_users_id`, and `google_users_id`. Only one of them may be non-null.

You can make sure that only one of them is non-null in code, or even in the database, with a trigger or perhaps even with a constraint.

Comment: Mike the number of columns may diverge with this design if new account types are included. thanks

Comment: Yes, the number of columns may diverge, and this is fine.  You cannot have referential integrity otherwise.

Comment: Mike, this have a cost that at present cannot be well determined. As Serg suggested, by reverting the reference keys the database integrity can be guaranteed ad well. Thanks

Comment: If you revert the reference keys you are going to need to do N queries to obtain a full row.  With my scheme  you only need 1 query with N joins, of which only 1 join will actually result in a search, since the other N-1 keys will be null.

Comment: I got your point but application knows which is the login type table. A single join should be enough to get the data needed. Application knows if user wants to log locally, facebook or whatever, so the login type table is identified at application level

Comment: Constraint in postgresql to validate one of the is non-null: `constraint chk_user check (facebook_users_id is not null or google_users_id is not null)`

Comment: @SarvarNishonboyev thank you very much for the addition. I amended the answer to indicate that it could also be done with a constraint, but I am not adding your exact suggestion yet, because I do not think it is entirely correct.  I think that your code snippet checks against forgetting to set at least one of the ids to non-null, which is desirable, but it fails to check against the case of mistakenly setting more than one id to non-null.